# Identifying a Texan horned butterfly

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

I found this butterfly on some late-season bluebonnets in Fort Worth, Texas, this evening.  You can get some sense of scale if you know how big bluebonnets are; the body is probably about the size of my thumbnail, but the 'horn' made it longer.

[image: Horned butterfly on bluebonnet]

Comment: Great job on providing enough detail for an ID. I've edited your post a bit (including taking out the moth part since the antennae are clearly butterfly-like). One helpful tool for identifications is ["Google Lens"](https://lens.google.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be an [American (or common) snout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_snout) [(*Libytheana carinenta*)](http://tolweb.org/Libytheana_carinenta/70293).

The "snout" of this butterfly is very distinctive as is the squarish tip of the forewings (the part projecting furthest back to the left in your picture.

Did you see the top surfaces of the wings? They should have had a dusty orange and brown pattern with white spots.

These butterflies are found from [Texas to Canada](http://texasento.net/snout.htm) and related species are seen in the Caribbean.
[image: American Snout (Libytheana carinenta), Merrimac Farm Wildlife Management Area, Nokesville, Virginia by Judy Gallagher]
Image: [Judy Gallagher](https://www.flickr.com/photos/52450054@N04/) [CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/).

Comment: I only saw it perched, so I didn't get to see the top surface, but, as you say, the snout is hard to miss, and the wings also had that squarish tip that you mention, so this seems like it must be it.  Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome :-)